# Setting Label.Text too frequently causes an app crash - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mqtt, tizen

I am working on an MQTTnet application for mobile/wearable devices. I've tested my code in both a standard C# Console application and .Net Core application, both work as expected. The issue I am having is when I port the code to Xamarin Forms, for running on a Galaxy Watch. The app will run for a few seconds, but then it will crash. I believe it could be from assigning the Label text too often?

I have an MQTT publisher device pumping out a simple position value at a 10ms interval. Where my other apps will just keep chugging along, the app in Xamarin will lock and then eventually crash. If it comment out the Label.Text assignment, the app keeps running without a crash.

Here is my Xamarin code, is there a better way to handle the assignment?

```
                // Event Handler to the ApplicationMessageRecevied event
                client.ApplicationMessageReceived += (s, e) =>
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the following to assign the label works well. My publisher is sending messages at 2ms intervals, and the watch is stable!

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        PositionData.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
                    });
```